# Android: what is the appropriate method to incorporate two classes into an activity

Tags: android, class, extends

I have two classes 1.MainActivity which extends Activity and 2.AlarmReceiver which extends BroadcastReceiver. How do I eliminate AlarmReceiver and instead implement its functions in the MainActivity? I understand you can not extend two classes so I'm wondering what is the best approach. Any help would be much appreciated.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        scheduleNextUpdate();
         Streamer str = new Streamer();
            Calendar calendar = str.getIcs();


        int x = 1;
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);

        for (Iterator i = calendar.getComponents().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            Component component = (Component) i.next();
            TextView tv_1 = new TextView(this);
            layout.addView(tv_1);
            tv_1.setText("Component " + x);
            x++;;

            for (Iterator j = component.getProperties().iterator(); j.hasNext();) {
                Property property = (Property) j.next();
                TextView tv_2 = new TextView(this);
                layout.addView(tv_2);
                tv_2.setText(property.getName() + ": " + property.getValue());
            }
        }

    }

    public void scheduleNextUpdate()
      {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long nextUpdateTimeMillis = (currentTimeMillis *2) + DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS;
        Time nextUpdateTime = new Time();
        nextUpdateTime.set(nextUpdateTimeMillis);

        if (nextUpdateTime.hour < 8 || nextUpdateTime.hour >= 22)
        {
          nextUpdateTime.hour = 8;
          nextUpdateTime.minute = 0;
          nextUpdateTime.second = 0;
          nextUpdateTimeMillis = nextUpdateTime.toMillis(false) + DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS;
        }
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
       // alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, nextUpdateTimeMillis, pendingIntent);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+10000,60000,pendingIntent);

        Streamer str = new Streamer();
        boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, 
                new Intent(MainActivity.this,AlarmReceiver.class), 
                PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);

        if (alarmUp)
        {
            Log.d("myTag", "Alarm is already active");
        }
        System.out.println(currentTimeMillis);
      }
```

AlarmReceiver

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  
        Log.d("myTag", "Alarm has been received");
    intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
     Streamer str = new Streamer();
        Calendar calendar = str.getIcs();
        System.out.println(calendar);
}

}
```

Comment: Does `AlarmReceiver` need to be able to receive a broadcast at all times, or only when `MainActivity` is running?

Comment: When MainActivity is running. The idea is that it will pull a file every 15 minutes and update the main screen with the most current information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register the `BroadcastReceiver` in your Activity and then unregister it in `onPause`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent("TESTING");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000, 10000, pendingIntent);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("TESTING"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        super.onPause();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks antew. I do have a few questions though.Should my intent be now directed to Mainactivity or to receiver? also should the manifest be changed to MainActivity.class or receiver.class?

Comment: I believe it should now be directed to `MainActivity`, and I don't think the `<receiver>` element in the `Manifest` is necessary since it is tied to the `Activity` in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't seem to be able to get it to work. I removed the<receiver> as it was casusing errors however when I set my intent as  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class); in the scheduleupdatemethod the Broadcast receiver does not appear to be called?

Comment: Hi Diarmuid, I updated my answer above.  I was incorrect on registering the intent, it should've been `Intent intent = new Intent("SOME_ACTION");`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help. It is much appreciated.